# Disabling In-App Purchases in Chrome extension I no longer support

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, in-app-purchase, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I have an extension that has 2 in-app subscription items. I unpublished the extension months ago, but the Chrome Web Store does not allow disabling in-app purchases, OR deleting an item from the store. I also updated the store listing begging no one to install or purchase any in-app items, but I logged in today after receiving a strange voicemail from an angry customer that had subscribed to both in-app purchases. I was horrified to learn that if you don't update your extension, users of an old version can (and will) purchase in-app subscriptions that my extension cannot deliver anymore. I've had to go through every purchase, refund the order, then cancel each subscription.

Is there a way to stop this? The code that I had published has been totally re-written and published under a different extension now, so there's not a practical way to release a new version that disables the in-app purchases, and that won't affect existing installations that are not updated anyway. The Chrome App Store is a HUGE cluster with very little thought towards developers managing their products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you do not want to maintain nor support the old extensions any more, just publish an update that removes the extension (the extension can be unlisted):

`manifest.json` (the version number must be higher than your currently published version)

```js
{
    "name": "Do not use me",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

`background.js` (using [`chrome.management.uninstallSelf`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-uninstallSelf)):

```js
chrome.management.uninstallSelf();
```